# Cakephp multiple applications in root folder

Tags: cakephp

I have two apps and I want to access the first app by http://localhost/ (Note: no app1 folder specified here) and the second by http://localhost/app2/. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

why not working with virtual hosts?
thats the right way to do it:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

you can have as many "vhosts" as you want. this will also enable you to work locally as you would live (on the webserver).